# how to update or insert data to spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I have a entity with 100,000 datas in hbase, I loaded all the data to the below RDD
JavaPairRDD rowPairRDD

When one data was inserted or updated in hbase. I want to update the rowPairRDD accordingly.
Is there any way to insert a data to rowPairRDD or update an specified data in RDD? thanks

Answer (score 4):

RDDs are immutable. They are not a read/write data structure. You would recreate an RDD from HBase to get new values.

Comment: currently  I used 2 RDD, the first RDD1 load all data from one entity in hbase when app inital. the second RDD2 load the new updates or inserts. At last even RDD1 and RDD2 only 0 or 1 data, RDD1 union RDD2 need to take 4 seconds. very slow. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: terrible answer given that data can be appended as long as you create a new rdd.

Comment: That's like saying you can update an immutable list because you can make a second immutable list with more data. It's not what update means.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this project: https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd. But updating the RDD  automatically when the data change in hbase is not feasible (assuming that your RDD is cached)...you have to update it by yourself.